# iTunes win32com Python - AddTrack not working

Tags: python, win32com, itunes-sdk

I've been using the following code to try and create a new playlist in iTunes and a song from the main library - its example code i've found but i keep getting the following error when it runs. I've had a look through the iTunes COM interface documentation and it seems that AddTrack is only available under IITLibraryPlaylist but all of the example code Ive found is as below. Can anyone help>

Error: AttributeError: win32com.ge_py.iTunes 1.13 Type Library.IITPlaylist instance at 0x34035192 object has no attribute 'AddTrack'

Python Code:

```
import win32com.client

itunes = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch ("iTunes.Application")

mainLibrary = itunes.LibraryPlaylist
tracks = mainLibrary.Tracks

playlist = itunes.CreatePlaylist("Sonic Jams")
song = tracks.ItemByName('Teen Age Riot')
playlist.AddTrack(song)
```

Answer (score 2):

in C#
Cast to IITUserPlayList

```
IITUserPlaylist rclibrary = (IITUserPlaylist)itunes.LibrarySource.Playlists.ItemByName["name"];
 rclibrary.AddTrack(item);
```

Answer (score 1):

i managed to get it using this code if anyone else needs it.

```
playlist = win32com.client.CastTo(itunes.CreatePlaylist("New List"), 'IITLibraryPlaylist')    
song = tracks.ItemByName('Silver Rocket')
playlist.AddTrack(song)
```